# How to get the column by its index instead of a name?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following initial PySpark DataFrame:

```
+----------+--------------------------------+
|product_PK|                        products|
+----------+--------------------------------+
|      686 |          [[686,520.70],[645,2]]|
|      685 |[[685,45.556],[678,23],[655,21]]|
|      693 |                              []|
```

```py
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
    [(686, [[686,520.70], [645,2]]), (685, [[685,45.556], [678,23],[655,21]]), (693, [])],
    ["product_PK", "products"]
)
```

The column `products` contains nested data. I need to extract the second value in each pair of values. I am running this code:

```py
temp_dataframe = dataframe.withColumn("exploded" , explode(col("products"))).withColumn("score", col("exploded").getItem("_2"))
```

It works well with particular DataFrame. However, I want to put this code into a function and run it on different DataFrames. All of my DataFrames have the same structure. The only difference is that the sub-column `"_2"` might be named differently in some DataFrames, e.g. `"col1"` or `"col2"`.

For example:

```
DataFrame content
root
 |-- product_PK: long (nullable = true)
 |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- exploded: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: double (nullable = true)
```

```
DataFrame content
root
 |-- product_PK: long (nullable = true)
 |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- product_PK: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col2: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- exploded: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- product_PK: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col2: integer (nullable = true)
```

I tried to use index like `getItem(1)`, but it says that the name of a column must be provided.

Is there any way to avoid specifying the column name or somehow generalize this part of a code?

My goal is that `exploded` contains the second value of each pair in the nested data, i.e. `_2` or `col1` or `col2`.

Comment: I _think_ that since `struct` does _not_ have to keep the order of fields (similarly to a map) you'd have to access the 2nd item by finding it by type, i.e. `integer`. That could work. Also, you know the schema of the input DataFrame so why don't you find the field name before `explode`?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: I can get field names using `temp_dataframe.schema.names`. But how should I access the required field in these schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you were on the right track.  I think the way to accomplish this is to read the schema to determine the name of the field you want to explode on.  Instead of schema.names though, you need to use schema.fields to find the struct field, and then use it's properties to figure out the fields in the struct.  Here is an example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Setup the test dataframe
data = [
    (686, [(686, 520.70), (645, 2.)]), 
    (685, [(685, 45.556), (678, 23.), (655, 21.)]), 
    (693, [])
]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("product_PK", StringType()),
    StructField("products", 
        ArrayType(StructType([
            StructField("_1", IntegerType()),
            StructField("col2", FloatType())
        ]))
    )
])

df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, schema) 

# Find the products field in the schema, then find the name of the 2nd field
productsField = next(f for f in df.schema.fields if f.name == 'products')
target_field = productsField.dataType.elementType.names[1]

# Do your explode using the field name
temp_dataframe = df.withColumn("exploded" , explode(col("products"))).withColumn("score", col("exploded").getItem(target_field))
```

Now, if you examine the result you get this:

```
>>> temp_dataframe.printSchema()
root
 |-- product_PK: string (nullable = true)
 |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- col2: float (nullable = true)
 |-- exploded: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col2: float (nullable = true)
 |-- score: float (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Let me test your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
>>> df.show(10, False)
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|product_PK|products                                                               |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|686       |[WrappedArray(686, null), WrappedArray(645, 2)]                        |
|685       |[WrappedArray(685, null), WrappedArray(678, 23), WrappedArray(655, 21)]|
|693       |[]                                                                     |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+

>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> df.withColumn("exploded", F.explode("products")) \
...   .withColumn("exploded", F.col("exploded").getItem(1)) \
...   .show(10,False)
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|product_PK|products                                                               |exploded|
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|686       |[WrappedArray(686, null), WrappedArray(645, 2)]                        |null    |
|686       |[WrappedArray(686, null), WrappedArray(645, 2)]                        |2       |
|685       |[WrappedArray(685, null), WrappedArray(678, 23), WrappedArray(655, 21)]|null    |
|685       |[WrappedArray(685, null), WrappedArray(678, 23), WrappedArray(655, 21)]|23      |
|685       |[WrappedArray(685, null), WrappedArray(678, 23), WrappedArray(655, 21)]|21      |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: In both cases I get the error `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Field name should be String Literal, but it's 1;"`

Comment: I'm using Spark 2.2.0

Comment: If I run `pyspark --version`, I get Spark 2.2 and Scala 2.11.8

Comment: @Markus, this is strange. I'm using: Spark version 2.2.0.cloudera1 and Scala version 2.11.8

Comment: Yes, strange. I can only use `getItem` with the column name. Therefore I was unable to find workaround myself. Thanks anyway!

Comment: [Docs says](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html): `An expression that gets an item at position ordinal out of a list, or gets an item by key out of a dict.`

Comment: Maybe it happens because I have empty data (`[]`) in `products`? Take a look at me example.

Comment: @Markus, i'm using your example... ;-)

Comment: I really don't know why it does not work for me. The approach of RyanW does not give me any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your `exploded` column is a `struct` as

```
 |-- exploded: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col2: float (nullable = true)
```

You can use following logic to get the second element without knowing the name

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
temp_dataframe = df.withColumn("exploded" , F.explode(F.col("products")))
temp_dataframe.withColumn("score", F.col("exploded."+temp_dataframe.select(F.col("exploded.*")).columns[1]))
```

you should have output as

```
+----------+--------------------------------------+------------+------+
|product_PK|products                              |exploded    |score |
+----------+--------------------------------------+------------+------+
|686       |[[686,520.7], [645,2.0]]              |[686,520.7] |520.7 |
|686       |[[686,520.7], [645,2.0]]              |[645,2.0]   |2.0   |
|685       |[[685,45.556], [678,23.0], [655,21.0]]|[685,45.556]|45.556|
|685       |[[685,45.556], [678,23.0], [655,21.0]]|[678,23.0]  |23.0  |
|685       |[[685,45.556], [678,23.0], [655,21.0]]|[655,21.0]  |21.0  |
+----------+--------------------------------------+------------+------+
```